# VB.NET Save file to ARM Cortex-M3 Microcontroller

Tags: vb.net, serial-port, cortex-m

I am currently in the process of making a Visual Basic.NET application that uses Serial communication to save a file to an [ST32 Contact ARM Cortex-M3 Secure Microcontroller (ST32F384)](http://www.st.com/content/st_com/en/products/secure-mcus/secure-hardware-platforms/st32-arm-cortex-m3/st32f384.html), and I am a bit confused with how the data is uploaded to the microcontroller. I have done research about sending serial data to and from the device, but could not find anything on how to actually save a file to the flash sector. Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the documentation for this part is right there on the page you linked.  The parts have a bootloader which you assert boot0 in a certain way on power up or reset and it goes into that, documentation on that protocol should be right there or the reference manual for the part will tell you the name of the manual for that protocol.  Also there is SWD (jtag like) which you can use, if this st part is on a discovery or nucleo board you have an stlink debugger built in from which you can use SWD (openocd works well).  If you dont then buying a $10 nucleo board, one of the wider ones with the break off stlink front end (dont need to break it off just remove two jumpers) is cheaper than a dedicated stlink dongle.  if you chip is on a nucleo board then when plugged into your computer it shows up as a flash drive and you simply drag and drop/copy your .bin file to that drive and the debugger on the board takes care of flashing.

This is all documented right there on the st site, no need to go any further.